# SQL SELECT Question of a current problem that I have to solve

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

Just a simple question of SQL that I was not able to figure out the solution.

```
table 2 AUditLog
Machine     SettingCode     User        changeSTR       timeChanged     Order
A              C1           U1          0->10           12/5/2020 10h00   1
A              C1           U2          10->3           12/5/2020 10h07   1
A              C1           U1           0->3           12/5/2020 11h00   3
```

I want to do a select of this table AuditLog and have. (in the cases of the same machine,  settingCode, Order) I want to have a result with the users of the most recente change.

```
Machine SettingCode     LastUserChange      Order
A       C1               U2                  1
A       C1               U1                  3
```

Comment: please post what you have tried: statements, results

Answer (score 0):

A simple and portable solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from auditLog a
where a.timeChanged = (
    select max(a1.timeChanged) 
    from auditLog a1 
    where 
        a1.machine = a.machine 
        and a1.settingCode = a.settingCode 
        and a1.order = a.order
)
```

You can also use `row_number()`, if your database, which you did not tell, supports window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        a.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by machine, settingCode, a.order 
            order by timeChanged desc) rn
    from auditLog a
) a
where rn = 1
```

Note that `order` is a SQL keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name.